# How to use comparison operators in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, test

How can I use `<=`, `>=`, `>`, and `<` in bash?

Instead of:

```
if [[ $arg1 -ge $num1 && $arg2 -le $num2 ]]; then
     ...
fi
```

Have something more like:

```
if [[ $arg1 >= $num1 && $arg2 <= $num2 ]]; then
     ...
fi
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18668580/1032785

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These operator are used in, e.g., `(( ... ))` and `$(( ... ))` (*arithmetic evaluation* and *arithmetic expansion* respectively):

```
if (( arg1 >= num1 )) && (( arg2 <= num2 )); then
    ...
fi
```

And also with `let`.  The following is equivalent of the above:

```
if let "arg1 >= num1" && let "arg2 <= num2"; then
    ...
fi
```

See the section named "ARITHMETIC EVALUATION" in the Bash manual.

Answer (score 4):

In `bash` specifically:

- `((arg1 >= num1))` (inherited from `ksh`) does arithmetic comparison. `arg1` and `num1` here refer to the shell variables of the same name. Each variable is interpreted as an arithmetic expansion and the result substituted. Here if `$arg1` is `010` and `$num1` is `4+5`, the result will be *false* (the `((...))` command will return with a non-zero exit status), because `010` is octal for 8 and `4+5` is 9.
- `(($arg1 >= $num1))`: same as above except that `$arg1` and `$num1` are expanded before that whole arithmetic expression is evaluated. If `$arg1` was `(2` and `$num1` was `2)`, the previous command would have failed because `(2` and `2)` are not valid expressions on their own. But here it would succeed because `(2 >= 2)` would be the arithmetic expression being evaluated. Generally, within arithmetic expressions, it's better to leave the `$` out. Compare for instance `a=2+2; echo "$((3 * $a))"` with `a=2+2; echo "$((3 * a))"`.
- `let "..."` (also from ksh). Same as `((...))` except that it's parsed as a normal command, is less legible, is as little portable and you need to pay closer attention to quoting.
- `[ "$arg1" -ge "$num1" ]`. That's standard and portable. Only decimal constants are supported. `[ 010 -ge 9 ]` is the same as `[ 10 -ge 9 ]`.
- `[[ $arg1 -ge $num1 ]]`. Also from ksh but with major differences. This time, `$arg1` and `$num1` are considered as arithmetic expressions and not just decimal constants. `[[ 010 -ge 9 ]]` returns false again.
- `[[ $arg1 < $num1 ]]`. String comparison. That uses `strcoll()` to compare strings, so using the sorting algorithm in the locale. Note that while `<` and `>` use the sorting algorithm, `=`/`==` do byte-to-byte comparison, so there may be pairs of strings for which all of `<`, `>` and `=`/`==` return false. `<=` and `>=` are not supported.
- `[ "$arg1" "<" "$num1" ]`. Non-standard. Same as above but using the `[` command. `<` needs to be quoted so it's not taken as a redirection operator.
- `expr " $arg1" "<=" " $num1" > /dev/null` (note the embedded spaces to force lexical comparison and avoid issues with strings looking like `expr` operators) or `awk 'BEGIN{exit(!(""ARGV[1] <= ""ARGV[2]))}' "$arg1" "$num1"` are the standard commands to do string comparison using `strcoll()`.